# In Corda, how can I include additional database drivers in my node at runtime?

Tags: corda

Is it possible to configure my node to include additional database driver JARs at runtime? If yes, how do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include additional JARs in your node at runtime as follows:

1. Open the node's configuration file (`node.conf`), and use the `jarDirs` option to specify the directories containing the JARs you wish to include in your node

   - The directories are specified using a relative path, and can be inside or outside of the node folder
2. Place the desired JARs in one of the specified folders
3. Start the node

If you are looking to use a different node database, you also need to use the `dataSourceProperties` option in `node.conf` to specify your database's data source and other options.